# Which regular expression methods to validate input could be used in shell scripting?

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, test

```
#!/bin/sh

re="\/$"

if [ $1 =~ $re ]; then
        echo "${ATTENTION_PREFIX}$1 DIRECTORY MAY NOT CONTAIN A \"/\" OR LITERAL SLASH!${ATTENTION_POSTFIX}"
        exit 1
fi
```

Executing `./file.sh hello/` results in `[: 29: hello: unexpected operator`

It looks like that this regular expression method is incorrect for shell scripting.

Comment: What's the relevance of `sudo` here? Don't use it needlessly

Comment: Why do you need to use a regular expression to check whether a string ends in a slash?  A test like `[ "$1" != "${1%/}" ]` would do that in a portable way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard `test` command also known as `[` doesn't have a `=~` operator. Most shells have that command built-in nowadays.

The Korn shell introduced a `[[...]]` construct (not a `[[` command) with alternate syntax and different parsing rules.

`zsh` and `bash` copied that to some extent with restrictions and many differences but that never was standardized, so shouldn't be used in portable `sh` scripts.

`ksh93` always had a way to convert an extended regexp to its globs with:

```
pattern=${ printf %P "regexp"; }
```

And you could then do:

```
[[ $var = $pattern ]]
```

Later ([in ksh93l in 2001](https://github.com/ksh93/ksh93-history/commit/d2095dbe686c99aa37bee3a1dd769011445b6c21#diff-0621942e0e7bef68561c72fbb299a16579069cce25a8f004af0a82f00e2528d2)) it also incorporated regular expressions in its globs like with the `~(E)regex` syntax for extended regular expressions, so you can do:

```
[[ $var = ~(E)regex ]]
```

That kind of pattern matching only works with the `[[...]]` construct or `case`, not the `[` command.

`zsh` added a regexp matching operator for both its `[` command and `[[...]]` first in 2001 with a `pcre` module. The syntax was initially `[ string -pcre-match regex ]` or `[[ string -pcre-match regex ]]`.

[`bash` added a `=~` operator in bash 3.0](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-3.0-beta#n102) (in 2004). Using extended regular expressions. That was added shortly after by ksh93 and zsh as well (again with differences).

`ksh93` and [`bash-3.2` and above](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-3.2-beta#n21) (when the `compat31` option is not enabled) use quoting to *escape* regexp operator causing all sorts of confusion (and it's very buggy in ksh93) and meaning it can't be used the same way with the `[` command there. `zsh` doesn't have that problem (quotes are used for shell quoting, and backslash to escape regex operator as usual), so the `=~` operator works in `zsh`'s `[` command (though itself needs quoted since `=foo` is a filename expansion operator in `zsh`).

`yash` doesn't have `[[...]]` but its `[` command has a `=~` operator (using EREs) and works as you'd expect (like `zsh`'s).

(**2023 edit**) Support for `[[...]]` was added in yash in 2.49 (2018) and `=~` in there works like bash's with regards to quoting.

In any case, neither `[[...]]` nor `=~` are POSIX operators and should not be used in `sh` scripts. The standard command to do regular expression matching on strings is `expr`:

```
if expr "x$var" : "x$regex" > /dev/null; then...
```

Note that `expr` regexps are anchored at the start, and you need that `x` trick to avoid problems with `$var` values that are `expr` operators. `expr` uses basic regexp, not extended regexps.

Most of the time however, you don't need regexp as simple shell pattern matching is enough for most cases:

```
case $var in
  (pattern) echo matches
esac
```

Comment: This works in a shell script and this answers the question. `sudo sh test.sh w` test.sh: `(\w) echo matches` results in `matches` Thank you.

Comment: Oh, but when i type `sudo sh test.sh h` then there is no match. The expectation is that `(\w)` should match all word characters.

Comment: @utrecht, why would you have such an expectation? `\w` is not mentioned in the `sh` man page or the POSIX spec for the standard shells. To check for alnum or underscore (which `\w` means in _some_ regular expression syntaxes), it's `case $var in ([[:alnum:]_]) ...`

Comment: Thank you. `([a-z])` works to match e.g. a and `[0-9]` works for single digits.

Comment: @utrecht, `[a-z]` only makes sense in C locales. If you intend to match any lowercase later, that should be `[[:lower:]]`. If you mean only the US ASCII characters from `a` to `z` and not the other ones like those in my first name, you may use either `[[:lower:]]` or `[a-z]` but after having fixed the locale to C (`LC_ALL=C`). In other locales (even in the US, nowadays, the locale is generally not C but UTF-8 based), `[a-z]` may match `B`, may match `é` but not `ẑ`...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have tested `[[:lower:]]` and it works and I will use this from now on instead of `[a-z]`

Answer (score 6):

Change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`, and use double brackets instead:

```
if [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then
```

This is the extended test command, as opposed to the (regular) test command. `=~` can only be used with the `[[  ... ]]` version, and requires Bash 3.0 or later.

Answer (score 5):

In `bash` old test `[` does not support regex. You must use new test `[[` instead:

```
re="\/$"

if [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then
        echo "${ATTENTION_PREFIX}$1 DIRECTORY MAY NOT CONTAIN A \"/\" OR LITERAL SLASH!${ATTENTION_POSTFIX}"
        exit 1
fi
```

You can see more [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).

You'll need to change your `#!/bin/sh` shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`, as well.

Comment: That's inaccurate. That's not about old vs new, that's about one implementation vs another.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Can you give more details?

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Great answer! But I think the old vs new is right with `bash`, I added it to my answer.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It's both: bash doesn't recognize the `=~` operator with the `[` builtin, only with the `[[ … ]]` syntax.