# How does one use regex to check input between 0-5 in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

What is the regex pattern for checking for a single digit number within a range?
I am trying the following pattern which seems to work when tested on
`https://regex101.com/`.

pattern: \b([0-5])\b

Expected result:

input : 2  output : ok

input : 5 output : ok

input : 6 output : no

input : 22 output : no

```
test$ ch=2
test$ [[ $ch =~ \b([0-5])\b ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
test$ ch=6
test$ [[ $ch =~ \b([0-5])\b ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
test$ ch=62
test$ [[ $ch =~ \b([0-5])\b ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
test$ ch=0
test$ [[ $ch =~ \b([0-5])\b ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
test$
```

I have tried double back as well:

```
test$ ch=2
test$ [[ $ch =~ \\b[0-5]\\b ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
test$ [[ $ch =~ \\b([0-5])\\b ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"
no
```

In my case, the bash is always giving out 'no'. Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: Related: [bash conditional expression and backslash escaping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617083/bash-conditional-expression-and-backslash-escaping)

Comment: And you don't want `\b` there, even if the bash regex flavor supported it, since that would consider something like `foo 5 bar` valid input. Instead, you want `^` and `$` to make sure you are testing the entire string.

Answer (score 7):

To verify that `$ch` is any one of the ASCII digits `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, or `5`, use:

- Portable (`sh` syntax):

  ```
  case $ch in 
    ([012345]) echo OK;;
    (*) echo not OK;;
  esac
  ```
- Korn-style alternative:

  ```
  if [[ $ch = [012345] ]]; then
    echo OK
  then
    echo not OK
  fi
  ```

Do *not* use ranges such as <strike>`[0-5]`</strike> for input validation as (depending on system and locale) that tends to include many other characters that happen to sort between 0 and 5 beside 012345 such as ٠١٢٣٤۰۱۲۳۴߀߁߂߃߄०१२३४০১২৩৪੦੧੨੩੪૦૧૨૩૪୦୧୨୩୪௦௧௨௩௪౦౧౨౩౪౸౹౺౻౼౽౾೦೧೨೩೪൦൧൨൩൪෦෧෨෩෪๐๑๒๓๔໐໑໒໓໔༠༡༢༣༤༪༫༬༭༳၀၁၂၃၄႐႑႒႓႔፩፪፫፬០១២៣៤៰៱៲៳៴᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧚᪀᪁᪂᪃᪄᪐᪑᪒᪓᪔᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔⁰⁴₀₁₂₃₄⅐⅑⅒⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅛⅜⅟↉①②③④⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳⑴⑵⑶⑷⑽⑾⑿⒀⒁⒂⒃⒄⒅⒆⒇⒈⒉⒊⒋⒑⒒⒓⒔⒕⒖⒗⒘⒙⒚⒛⓪⓫⓬⓭⓮⓯⓰⓱⓲⓳⓴⓵⓶⓷⓸⓾⓿❶❷❸❹❿➀➁➂➃➉➊➋➌➍➓〇〡〢〣〤㉈㉉㉊㉋㉑㉒㉓㉔㉕㉖㉗㉘㉙㉚㉛㉜㉝㉞㉟㊱㊲㊳㊴㊵㊶㊷㊸㊹㊺㊻㊼㊽㊾㋀㋁㋂㋃㋉㋊㋋㍘㍙㍚㍛㍜㍢㍣㍤㍥㍦㍧㍨㍩㍪㍫㍬㍭㍮㍯㍰㏠㏡㏢㏣㏩㏪㏫㏬㏭㏮㏯㏰㏱㏲㏳㏴㏵㏶㏷㏸㏹㏺㏻㏼㏽㏾꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꧐꧑꧒꧓꧔꧰꧱꧲꧳꧴꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꯰꯱꯲꯳꯴０１２３４

You could also use regex `[[ $ch =~ ^[012345]$ ]]` but that has little advantage over using `case` or `[[...]]`'s `=`.

It could be useful to match on any integer decimal representation of a number in between 0 and 5 including `-0`, `0004`, `+5` which you could do with:

```
[[ $ch =~ ^(-0+|\+?0*[012345])$ ]]
```

Which is slightly shorter than the Korn-style:

```
[[ $ch = @(-+(0)|?(+)*(0)[012345]) ]]
```

And likely easier to read by people familiar with regexps.

Never use arithmetic operators of the `[[...]]` construct (as in <strike>`[[ $ch -ge 0 && $ch -le 5 ]]`</strike>) nor `((...))` (as in `(( ch >= 0 && ch <= 5 ))`) for input validation as [those introduce arbitrary command execution vulnerabilities](/q/172103). `[ "$ch" -ge 0 ] && [ "$ch" -le 5 ]` doesn't have the problem in bash but would output errors upon incorrect numbers and would allow blanks around the numbers.

`\b([0-5])\b` is a perl regexp (the default at https://regex101.com), that matches on any one of the 012345 characters preceded and followed by a *word `b`oundary*, that is *provided it's neither preceded nor followed by a word character*, word characters being alphanumeric ones and underscores. So for instance it would match in `123.5` because there's a `5` in there that is preceded by `.` which is not a word character and not followed by anything.

`bash`'s `=~` uses POSIX extended regular expressions, not perl regexps and the behaviour for `\b` in POSIX ERE is unspecified.

As https://regex101.com doesn't currently offer POSIX ERE as a choice of regex flavour, you shouldn't use it to validate regexps used in bash's `[[ =~ ]]` operator.

There are systems in which the extended regular expression matcher used by bash supports `\b` as an extension over the standard, but in `[[ $ch =~ \b[0-5]\b ]]`, bash treats `\b` as a quoted `b`, the same as if you had written `[[ $ch =~ 'b'[0-5]'b' ]]` and doesn't pass the backslash to the regex engine.

You can work around that by using:

```
regex='\b[012345]\b' # with the [0-5] also fixed to [012345]
[[ $ch =~ $regex ]]
```

Where the backslash will be passed to the regex matcher¹, but that will only work on systems that support that `\b` extension.

Doing it with standard ERE syntax would look like:

```
[[ $ch =~ (^|[^[:alnum:]_])[012345]([^[:alnum:]_]|$) ]]
```

To use perl-style regexps, you could switch to `zsh` which has a `rematchpcre` option to use PCRE (PCRE2 for now PCRE3 in the next version) in its own `=~` operator.

```
set -o rematchpcre
[[ $ch =~ '\b[0-5]\b' ]]
```

Would work there (and zsh doesn't have that misfeature of bash whereby shell quoting is treated as regexp escaping which also allows it to use other regexp engines).

zsh also has a glob operator to match ranges of decimal integer numbers so there `[[ $ch = <0-5> ]]` would match on `000`, `01`, `3`... And `[[ $ch = (-<0-0>|(+|)<0-5>) ]]` would do the same as `[[ $ch =~ '^(-0+|\+?0*[012345])$' ]]` (note the quotes around the regex as a difference with bash 3.2+).

---

<sup>¹ See [bash regexp matching fails in [[ ]]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/520618) and [How does storing the regular expression in a shell variable avoid problems with quoting characters that are special to the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382054) for details and [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140716) for the history of builtin regex matching in Korn-like shells.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Since your expression is subject to bash expansions the `\b` is being expanded to simply `b` before the regex is being checked (try `ch=b4b`).  Also it seems unnecessary to use a capture group.

You can put your expression in a variable first like so:

```
exp='\b[0-5]\b'
[[ $ch =~ $exp ]]
```

However for something like this I would much prefer using arithmetic operators:

```
[[ $ch -gt 0 && $ch -lt 6 ]]
```

or

```
((ch>0&&ch<6))
```

Comment: But I also want to check for if input is number as well as range in one regex.

Comment: @preetam if `ch` is not a number it will fail those checks just like it would the regex test

Comment: try this: `ch=44;nums=6;[[ $ch -gt 0 && $ch < $nums ]] && echo "ok" || echo "no"`
Doesn't work.

Comment: Depending on the system and locale, regexp `[0-5]` may match dozens of different characters that happen to sort in-between 0 and  5. Such as ², ³ or decimal digits in other scripts. Use `[012345]` if you only want to match on the arabic digits

Comment: **Never** use `[[...]]`'s arithmetic operators nor `((...))`  for input validation as that introduces command injection vulnerabilities. For instance with `ch='a[$(reboot)]'`, that would reboot.